# mailto: pull email address from item

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013

I am looking to have an email to send that will populate the e-mail address, Subject and Body of the e-mail. I tried the following but it will not work. Can someone assist?

```html
<script src="/SiteAssets/jquery-3.4.0.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  function SendMail()
  {
   var emailID = getEmailFromPeoplePicker('User Requesting Assistance');
   var subject = getSubject('Ticket Number');
   var body = getBody('Description of Problem');
   location.href = "mailto:"+emailID+"?subject="+subject+"&body="+body;
  }
  function getSubject(subject)
  {
   return $('input[title="'+subject+'"]').val();
  }
  function getBody(body)
  {
   return $('input[title="'+body+'"]').val();
  }
  function getEmailFromPeoplePicker(title) {
   //Get the people picker field
   var ppDiv = $("div[title='" + title + "']")[0];
   //cast the object as type PeoplePicker
   var peoplePicker = SPClientPeoplePicker.SPClientPeoplePickerDict[ppDiv.id];
   //Get list of users from field (assuming 1 in this case)
   var userList = peoplePicker.GetAllUserInfo();
   var userInfo = userList[0];
   var userEmail;
   //The description field contains the login info without the lookup extras.  In new forms this 
   //field can be undefined depending on the field being checked.  Only check if userInfo is
   //initialized.
   if(userInfo != null)
   {
    userEmail = userInfo.EntityData.Email;
   }
   return userEmail;
  }
</script>
<a href="#" onclick="SendMail()">Email User</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use the code in your post, the "Ticket Number" and "Description of Problem" will be all the single text field. If the "Description of Problem" field is multiple line of text field, the code will not works.

To get multiple lines of text, we can use the code below to achieve it. If you can't get the email of the user, you need check if the user have the email(go to user profile to check it).

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>  
<script type="text/javascript">
function SendMail(){
    var emailID = getEmailFromPeoplePicker('User Requesting Assistance');
    var subject = getSubject('Ticket Number');
    var body = getBody('Description of Problem');
    location.href = "mailto:"+emailID+"?subject="+subject+"&body="+body;
}
function getSubject(subject){
    return $('input[title="'+subject+'"]').val();
}
function getBody(body){
    return  $('nobr:contains("'+body+'")').closest('tr').find('.ms-rtestate-write')[0].innerText;
}
function getEmailFromPeoplePicker(title) {
    //Get the people picker field
    var ppDiv = $("div[title='" + title + "']")[0];
    //cast the object as type PeoplePicker
    var peoplePicker = SPClientPeoplePicker.SPClientPeoplePickerDict[ppDiv.id];
    //Get list of users from field (assuming 1 in this case)
    var userList = peoplePicker.GetAllUserInfo();
    var userInfo = userList[0];
    var userEmail;
    //The description field contains the login info without the lookup extras.  In new forms this 
    //field can be undefined depending on the field being checked.  Only check if userInfo is
    //initialized.
    if(userInfo != null){
        userEmail = userInfo.EntityData.Email;
    }
    return userEmail;
}
</script>
<a href="#" onclick="SendMail()">Email User</a>
```